# Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field : Hibernate Spatial + Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, geometry, hibernate-spatial

I am trying to save Point data using Hibernate in Mysql. But I am not able to understand what am I doing wrong?

I am using hibernate 5.3.6, jts 1.14, mysql-connector-5.1.18.
The database has three fields id, name and curr_loc with type int, varchar and point respectively

The hibernate dialect I am using is org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect.

This is the entity class

```
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point;

@Entity
@Table(name = "location")
public class Location {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "curr_loc")
    private Point curr_loc;

//getters and setters
}
```

This the code in the main method of the class SaveLocation which stores the data using hibernate

```
public static void main(String args[]){

     SessionFactory factory = new Configuration()        
                                .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
                                .addAnnotatedClass(Location.class)
                                .buildSessionFactory();
     Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();

     GeometryFactory geometryFactory = new GeometryFactory();
     Point point = geometryFactory.createPoint( new Coordinate( 10, 5 ) );
     Location tempLocation = new Location("AMD", point);
     session.beginTransaction();
     session.save(tempLocation);
     session.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

When i try to use *MySQLSpatial56Dialect*, it gives me this error:
**Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLSpatial56Dialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]**

Also if I keep the dialect as *MySQLDialect* and then try to save the data I get the following error:
**ERROR: Data truncation: Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field**

Please suggest what am I doing wrong? Why am I not able to use MySQLSpatial56Dialect. More importantly what is the correct way to store a point in the database using hibernate. There is no proper example to implement the same. I am new to hibernate and I am not able to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should use "org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQL56SpatialDialect" or "org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQL8SpatialDialect" instead of "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect".

Check your mysql server version, it should be mysql 5.7 or later, or better using mysql8.